# jumping and moving in processing

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to get a circle to be able to jump and move left and right at the same time, but right now its either only jumping or moving forward at a time. Anyone know how to change my code to solve this? Thanks

```
float px,py,vx,vy,ax,ay;
boolean canJump = false;

void setup(){
  size(600, 400);
  ax = 0;
  ay = .32;
  vx = 0;
  vy = 0;
  px = 300;
  py = 200;
}

int x = 50;
int y = 520;

void draw(){
  background(0);
  ellipse(px-15, py-30, 60, 60);
  vx+=ax;
  vy+=ay;
  px+=vx;
  py+=vy;
  if( py > height ){
    py = height;
    vy = 0;
    canJump = true;
  }
  player();
}

void player(){
  fill(255);
  rect(0, 550, 1000, 50);
}

void keyPressed(){
  if(keyCode == RIGHT || key == 'd'){
    px += 10;
  }
  
  if(keyCode == LEFT || key == 'a'){
    px -= 10;
  }
  if(keyCode == UP){
    if(canJump) {
      vy = -10;
      canJump = false;
    }
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want a specific key to make a jump and move forward at the same time?

Comment: If you move both left and right at the same time then they cancel each other out because they move the exact same distance. What is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can make your ball go both up and right or up and left by checking that both keys are pressed and then you can add to the velocity instead of the position to affect the trajectory of the ball. However, then you must slow down the x component of the velocity when it hits the ground, so I added a `friction` variable.

```java
float px, py, vx, vy, ax, ay;
boolean canJump = false;

float bounce = 0.2;
float friction = 0.2;

void setup() {
  size(600, 400);
  ax = 0;
  ay = .32;
  vx = 0;
  vy = 0;
  px = 300;
  py = 200;
}

int x = 50;
int y = 520;

void draw() {
  background(0);
  ellipse(px-15, py-30, 60, 60);
  vx+=ax;
  vy+=ay;
  px+=vx;
  py+=vy;
  if ( py > height ) {
    py = height;
    vy = -bounce*vy;
    vx = friction*vx;
    canJump = true;
  }
}

void keyPressed() {  
  if (keyCode == RIGHT && keyCode == UP) {
    if (canJump) {
      vy = -10;
      vx += 5;
      canJump = false;
    }
  } else if (keyCode == LEFT && keyCode == UP) {
    if (canJump) {
      vy = -10;
      vx += -5;
      canJump = false;
    }
  } else {
    if (keyCode == RIGHT || key == 'd') {
      vx += 5;
    }

    if (keyCode == LEFT || key == 'a') {
      vx -= 5;
    }
    if (keyCode == UP) {
      if (canJump) {
        vy = -10;
        canJump = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can improve the implementation of your program by taking a look at processing's [`PVector`](https://processing.org/reference/PVector.html) class.

```java
PVector pos;
PVector vel;
PVector acc;

float friction = 0.3;
float bounce = 0.5;

float diameter = 60;

boolean canJump = false;

void setup() {
  size(600, 400);

  pos = new PVector(300, 200);
  vel = new PVector(0, 1);
  acc = new PVector(0, 0.32);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  circle(pos.x, pos.y, diameter);

  vel.add(acc);
  pos.add(vel);

  if (pos.y + diameter/2 > height) {
    pos.set(pos.x, height-diameter/2);
    vel.set(vel.x*friction, -vel.y*bounce);
    canJump = true;
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  boolean right = keyCode == RIGHT || key == 'd';
  boolean left = keyCode == LEFT || key == 'a';
  boolean up = keyCode == UP || key == 'w';


  if (up && right && canJump) {
    vel.add(5, -10);
    canJump = false;
  } else if (up && left && canJump) {
    vel.add(-5, -10);
    canJump = false;
  } else {
    if (up && canJump) {
      vel.add(0, -10);
      canJump = false;
    }

    if (right) {
      vel.add(5, 0);
    }

    if (left) {
      vel.add(-5, 0);
    }
  }
}
```